# Exercice Sheet in Korean - Word spacing optimization

Tags: spacing

I created this exercice sheet to memorize new korean words I learn by handwriting.
It actually works right now but I had to fit each caracters into a table cell with precise spacing to fit the frame.

Is there an easier way to achieve the same result without a table ?
I would just want to copy paste then compile.

Thanks

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article} % for A4 size paper
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={216mm,297mm},
 left=0.0mm,
 top=9mm,
 }
\usepackage{kotex}
\usepackage[letterspace=0]{microtype}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.59cm}
\newcommand{\versal}[1]{\textscale{0.9}{\textls*[80]{#1}}}
\newcommand{\blank}[1]{\hspace*{#1}\linebreak[0]}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{bookColor}{cmyk}{0 , 0  , 0   , 0.50}  % 0.90\% of black
\color{bookColor}

\begin{document}
%\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]

\tikzset{normal lines/.style={gray, very thin}} 
\tikzset{margin lines/.style={red, thick}} 
\tikzset{mm lines/.style={gray, ultra thin}} 
\tikzset{strong lines/.style={black, very thin}} 
\tikzset{master lines/.style={black, very thick}} 
\tikzset{dashed master lines/.style={loosely dashed, black, very thick}} 

\node at (current page.south west){
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw[style=normal lines,step=0.5cm] (0,0) grid +(210mm,290mm);
    \draw[style=strong lines,step=1cm] (0,0) grid +(210mm,290mm);
  \end{tikzpicture}
};
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{table}
\Large
\begin{tabular} 
{p{0.59cm}p{0.59cm}p{0.59cm}p{0.59cm}p{0.59cm}p{0.59cm}p{0.59cm}p{0.59cm}}
예&전\\[2.26mm]
부&추&김&치\\[2.26mm]
존&댓&말\\[2.26mm]
모&으&다\\[2.26mm]
감&각&류\\[2.26mm]
날&짜\\[2.26mm]
등&록&하&다\\[2.26mm]
후&회&하&다\\[2.26mm]
벌&다\\[2.26mm]
땀&을&흘&리&다\\[2.26mm]
쏟&다\\[2.26mm]
진&정&하&다\\[2.26mm]
입&주&하&다\\[2.26mm]
연&주&하&다\\[2.26mm]
담&다\\[2.26mm]
변&하&다\\[2.26mm]
무&시&하&다\\[2.26mm]

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\newpage
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]

\tikzset{normal lines/.style={gray, very thin}} 
\tikzset{margin lines/.style={gray, thick}} 
\tikzset{mm lines/.style={gray, ultra thin}} 
\tikzset{strong lines/.style={black, very thin}} 
\tikzset{master lines/.style={black, very thick}} 
\tikzset{dashed master lines/.style={loosely dashed, black, very thick}} 

\node at (current page.south west){
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]

    \draw[style=normal lines,step=0.5cm] (0,0) grid +(210mm,290mm); 
    \draw[style=strong lines,step=1cm] (0,0) grid +(210mm,290mm); 

  \end{tikzpicture}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{table}
\Large
\begin{tabular} 
{p{0.59cm}p{0.59cm}p{0.59cm}p{0.59cm}p{0.59cm}p{0.59cm}p{0.59cm}p{0.59cm}}
건&강&하&다\\[2.26mm]
휴&지&통\\[2.26mm]
조&건\\[2.26mm]
독&서\\[2.26mm]
환&경\\[2.26mm]
상&황\\[2.26mm]
열&린&마&음\\[2.26mm]

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: preview]

Comment: I don't know anything about korean, but maybe a monospace korean police would do the job?

Comment: you don't need to know anything a about korean, just need a defined space between 2 caracters. I would be pretty much the same as a precise space between a and b.

Comment: @sztruks “Police” should be “font”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using a googlesheet formula to convert it.

> =CONCATENATE(MID(S2;1;1);"&";MID(S2;1+1;1);"&";MID(S2;1+2;1);"&";MID(S2;1+3;1);"&";MID(S2;1+4;1);"&";MID(S2;1+5;1);"&";MID(S2;1+6;1);"&";MID(S2;1+7;1);"\[2.26mm]")

[image]